# Why can't I access my Bq Ubuntu phone on Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, ubuntu-touch, adb

I have my device in the developer mode and I can browse the internal storage via Nautilus so the USB connection is working. However, neither adb nor phablet-shell can "see" my device. The devices view in Qt Creator is empty. What could be the reason? Is this even supposed to work on Ubuntu 14.04? I have installed the newest developer stuff from the PPA.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sounds like your device vendor is not known to adb.

adb shows a device only when it knows the vendor of the device. The vendor of the bq E4.5 seems not known by default.

To change that edit or create the file ~/.android/adb_usb.ini and add the following line

```
0x2a47
```

That is the vendor id of the bq E4.5.

Restart the adb server after you edited the file

```
sudo adb kill-server;  sudo adb start-server
```

You can find out the id by yourself with lsusb. (I made the id bold so you can see where to look for it in the lsusb output)

Bus 003 Device 002: ID **2a47**:0c02

(Or you could execute lsusb -v and look for the idVendor field.)

Comment: I already almost lost my hope so thanks! :) It works now.

Comment: Qt Creator still doesn't see device, but at least adb works.

Comment: Thank you; works perfectly. Don't forget to switch you bq E4.5 to 'Developer Mode' in 'System Settings' --> 'Info' --> 'Developer Mode'. Otherwise adb will not see your device.