# adb shell on BQ Aquaris fails with "error: closed"

Tags: ubuntu-touch, adb

I'm trying to open an adb shell on my BQ Aquaris Ubuntu phone. Initially the command failed with a device not found error. Now after adding the phone's USB ID to a custom INI file as outlined [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/604100/why-cant-i-access-my-bq-ubuntu-phone-on-ubuntu-14-04) I get a different error:

```
error: closed
```

Any pointers as to what's going wrong here? How can I open a shell into my Ubuntu phone?

Any help is very much appreciated!!!

EDIT I have set my phone to developer mode and I'm using 14.04 on my desktop.

Comment: Is your phone screen turned on and unlocked when you try to connect via adb?

Comment: Wow! That did it! Thank you, Christopher! I didn't expect the solution to be that trivial. :) If you convert your comment to an answer I'll mark it as solved.

Comment: Glad it helped :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

adb can only connect to a device if the device's screen is **on** and **unlocked**.

This is a security measure so that no one can circumvent your lock screen by accessing your phone via adb. 
That is the reason that one has to set a lock to enable developer mode as well.

By unlocking your phone you give the proof to adb that you have the permission to access the phone and it will connect.